# retain form data for form post

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express and Flash to show error message when POST is fail.

I need to retain the Form data submitted that user key in, when I prompted the flash message.

How can I do it.

Comment: what templating you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to just have a kind of switch for that, you need to do it manually:

Pass the data back to the template - you're redirecting, so you'll need flash to get it to the route which renders the template with the form. Simply do something like

```
req.flash('formData', formData);
```

`formData` should hold the data coming from the form in whatever format is suitable for you to use in your template afterwards. If you have already sanitized the data you might wanna use the sanitized version to pass back.

Then pass the data to your template:

```
formData: req.flash('formData');
```

and use it in your template however you like (e.g. set the `value` attribute of the form fields).